# Can I add to lacto-ferment jars as I harvest?

Tags: fermentation

Last year I made lacto-fermented jalapenos from my garden and they were great! I took what was left at the end of the season plus I added some local peppers from the farmer's market in a mason jar and added my brine. This year my jalapeno plants are about ready for their first harvest. However, it isn't enough to "fill" my mason jar in one shot.

So my question is - can I start a lacto-ferment with the peppers I have on hand now, and then add additional peppers as they are harvested throughout the summer? I know that will mean I will have peppers at different stages of the process in the jar at the same time. Would I have to wait until all the peppers are fermented before eating or could I start taking out the "earlier" peppers as needed? Is this a valid approach or should I just suck it up and do smaller jars?